# Filter in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript. I need to filter (show/hide) lines by chosen option(All - show all rows, Closed - hide all options except Closed, Opened - only 'Opened' rows.).

Where am I doing something wrong? I want to understand it.
Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<select id="select">
   <option>All</option>
   <option>Closed</option>
   <option>Opened</option>
</select>

<div class="btn">
<input id='status-filter' type="submit" value="Ok"/>
...

<tr class='row' data-row-choice="Opened">
<tr class='row' data-row-choice="Opened">
<tr class='row' data-row-choice="Closed">
...
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').on('click', '#status-filter', function() {
        var selectOption = $('#select option:selected').text();
        $('.row').each(function(selectOption) {
            if ($('.row[data-row-choice]') == 'All') {
                $(this).show();
            } else if ($('.row[data-row-choice]') != selectOption) {
                $(this).hide();
            };
        });
    });
});
```

EDIT:
I mistook that 'All' - all rows('Opened' and 'Closed'), i.e. 'All' contains 'Opened' and 'Closed'. And I corrected another code.

Comment: You're using `#select` selector, but there's no such element in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where am I doing something wrong?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').on('click', '#status-filter', function() {
        var selectOption = $('#select option:selected').text();
```

Up until here it looks okay, assuming your `<select>` element has an id attribute equal to `"select"`, i.e. `<select id="select">...</select>`.

```
        $('.row').each(function(selectOption) {
```

The argument `selectOption` gets populated by jQuery with the index of the current element that's being iterated, e.g. `0`, `1`, etc... Drop the argument from the function declaration.

```
            if ($('.row[data-row-choice]') == 'All') {
```

You should check for the value of `selectOption` instead, because there won't be rows with that value.

```
                $(this).show();
            } else if ($('.row[data-row-choice]') != selectOption) {
                $(this).hide();
            };
```

You've left out items that were hidden before and should now be shown again.

```
        });
    });
});
```

#### Working example

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.btn').on('click', '#status-filter', function() {
    var selectedOption = $('#select').val();

    $('.row')
      .hide()
      .filter(function() {
        return selectedOption == 'All' || $(this).data('row-choice') == selectedOption;
      })
      .show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').on('click', '#status-filter', function() {
        var selectOption = $('#select option:selected').text();
        if(selectOption=="All") $("tr.row").show();
        else if(selectOption=="Closed") 
            {$("tr[data-row-choice='All'], tr[data-row-choice='Open']").hide();
            $("tr[data-row-choice='Closed']").hide();}
        else
            {$("tr[data-row-choice='All'], tr[data-row-choice='Closed']").hide();
            $("tr[data-row-choice='Open']").hide();}
    });
});
```